# js share class instance between files

Tags: javascript, typescript, store

I have a store instance that I want to share among my other files:

store

```
class Root {
    id: number = Math.random()
}

let Store = new Root()
export default Store
```

fileA

```
import Store from './store'
console.log(Store.id)
```

fileB

```
import Store from './store'
console.log(Store.id)
```

Both console.logs print different numbers. Therefore I assume that the store is instantiated twice.

How can I make sure that there is only one store and all files that import it can share the same instance?

Comment: what module loader are you using?

Comment: Did you fix your problem? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the store once, in your index and export that instance or pass it as an argument variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `process`. If you are executing both files(fileA and fileB) separately in different process, then it will always give you a new random number. But if you are executing both files from one parent file (`single process`) then, it will always give you same number due to caching mechanism of modules.