# How to reference current Vuex State and related Vue instance (this) inside javascript event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am working with vuex and vuejs.
I have currently 2 vue instances (I know it's bad but I can't do otherwise, it's not the question)

Sidebar.js vue definition :

```
//VUEX stores
import { dashboardStore } from './../../js/Stores/DefinitionMappingStores/VuexStoreForDashboardPage'

//first vue with initialisation of state
var vmSidebar = new Vue({
    el: '#sidebar-content',
    store: dashboardStore,
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('search/setMiniWidgets', miniwidgetsfromjson);
    },
})
```

Dashboard.js :

```
import { dashboardStore } from './../../js/Stores/DefinitionMappingStores/VuexStoreForDashboardPage'

//second vue where state is empty (array(0) instead of having 20+ items inside)
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#dashboard-container',
    store: dashboardStore,
    mounted: function () {
        let that = this; //take this reference, pointing to the current Vue instance
        let grid = GridStack.init(options, this.$refs["dashboardref"].$el); //initialise gridstack grid (javascript lib)
        grid.on('dropped', function (event, previousWidget, newWidget) { //here is a javascript event)
            console.log(this); console.log(that); //here this is the dropped div element / that is the vue instance saved before... but it keep the $store variable not following change...
            let vueMiniWidgetComponentFromSidebar = that.$store.getters['search/getFilteredMiniWidgetsById'](idFromNewAddedNode); //here the store search is not initialized but in the other vue from sidebar I see it initialized
        });
    },
})
```

SearchModule store :

```
const searchModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        miniWidgets: []
    },
    getters: {
        getFilteredMiniWidgetsById: (state) => (id) => {
            if (id == undefined || id == null || id == "") {
                return null;
            } else {
                return state.miniWidgets.find(miniWidget => miniWidget.Id === id)
            }
        }
    },
}
export default searchModule;
```

VuexStoreForDashboardPage.js :

```
import searchModule from './../SearchModuleStore.js'
import userTutorialModule from './../UserTutorialModuleStore.js'

//VUEX stores
export const dashboardStore = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        //a lot of others modules
        search: searchModule,
    },
})
```

I think my problem is that I save a "state" of the Vue instance, and not a reference to it, so everytime my grid.on function will be called, the "that" reference pointing to the Vue instance saved will be the same (the saved one).

So my question is : How to have my grid.on function getting the correct vue instance with the associated store changing ? And how to have the same Vuex store sharing information together inside those 2 files ?

**Edit :** When I am inspecting with Vue dev tool, In the components tab, in my second vue instance, my miniWidgets array is empty, and my first vue instance is correctly filled. If I am going to VueX tab, I see the state object correctly populated... Why my vuex store in my second vue instance is wrong then ?

**Edit 2** It's working when 2 vue instances are in the same file, but not when they are in 2 differents files and then imported in one file. Do you know how to correct that but with keeping these 2 files ?

Comment: Your store is shared between the 2 Vue instances - if you change the state from one of the instances, the other instance will also see the changed state. If you want to have 2 separate Vuex stores - then you should use a factory function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55273915/5962802)

Comment: I want the 2 vue instance change the same store. But for now, my second store is empty (like it was just initialized with default store values) and it's not changing from my first vue instance update. If I import and export my store like that, I normally share the vuex store right ?

Comment: Yes, you are exporting a CONST - so it will be shared between the 2 Vue instances.

Comment: but why my second this.$store in the 2nd vue instance is not updated then ? I also tried to export the vuex instance like `export const dashboardStore = () => {
 return new Vuex.Store({ ...})}` but it does the same

Comment: It will help if you can provide a minimal CodePen so we can reproduce your case.

Comment: I can't really do a fiddle here (I tried) because I have a babel+webpack config and import export everywhere (or if you know a codepen where I can create multiple files ?)

Comment: In 2 vue instances define in the same file it's working, but in 2 vue files defined into 2 separated file and bundled via webpack it didn't work. Do you know why ? I can't create one unique file here

Comment: Thank's @IVOGELOV to tried to help me, what I wanted to do is just impossible, I didn't known this specification before... I let you see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am trying to do is just *currently impossible*.

I found the same issue as me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47365388/).

### Solution 1 :

You need to generate the store once, for exemple here in Sidebar.js and then export that instance or pass it as an argument variable for the second one. It will word if you need that 2 stores shared the same instance in one way.
*In my case I need this to be working in two ways.*

### Solution 2 :

So, the only solution is not a real solution but it's to create a file with both Sidebar.js and Dashboard.js files. All are in the same scope and this is fine.

**Explanation :**

If you are executing both files(Sidebar.js and Dashboard.js) separately in different process, then it will always give you a new instance(store/vue). But if you are executing both files from one parent file (single process) then, it will always give you same instance(store/vue) due to caching mechanism of modules.

If one day this mechanism is changing, please feel free to contact me or to add your own answer here.